# Extension method for UPDATE in Linq to Objects

Tags: linq-to-objects

In the following scenario, I am querying a List object and for the matching predicate I want to update some values:

```
var updatedList = MyList
                 .Where (c => c.listItem1 != "someValue")  
                 .Update (m => {m.someProperty = false;});
```

The only issue is there is no Update extension method. How to go about this?

My objective is update only those items in my list which match the condition leaving the other items intact.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var people = new List<Person> {
                new Person{Name="aaa", Salary=15000, isHip=false}
                ,new Person{Name="aaa", Salary=15000, isHip=false}
                ,new Person{Name="bbb", Salary=20000, isHip=false}
                ,new Person{Name="ccc", Salary=25000, isHip=false}
                ,new Person{Name="ddd", Salary=30000, isHip=false}
                ,new Person{Name="eee", Salary=35000, isHip=false}
            };


            people.Where(p => p.Salary < 25000).Update(p => p.isHip = true);

            foreach (var p in people)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", p.Name, p.isHip);
            }


        }
    }

    class Person
    {

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Salary { get; set; }
        public bool isHip { get; set; }
    }


    public static class LinqUpdates
    {

        public static void Update<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action)
        {
            foreach (var item in source)
                action(item);
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Something makes me a little queasy about the Update method, but I suppose that wasn't the question.

Comment: Thanks Rob! Just started delving into this whole LINQ scene.

Comment: Note that this extension method is usually called "ForEach" because there's nothing in it which is specific to updates... it just executes for each item.

Answer (score 4):

Or you could use an extension method that comes with the .Net framework:

```
var updatedList = MyList
                 .Where (c => c.listItem1 != "someValue")  
                 .ForEach(m => m.someProperty = false);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(var item in MyList.Where(c => c.listItem1 != "someValue"))
{
    item.someProperty = false;
}
```