# Is there a extension library specifically for LINQ to Objects?

Tags: extension-methods, linq-to-objects

This question comes as a logical follow-up to one of my earlier questions:

[Extension method for UPDATE...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344140/extension-method-for-update-in-linq-to-objects)

I would like to know if there is a library specific for LINQ to Objects ... more specifically a set of ***useful extensions*** for **IEnumerable** ?

Here ... I do not want to know about the SQL entity or XML related extensions.
Is there an extension library specific for LINQ to Objects?

Answer (score 1):

LINQ to Objects itself lives within `System.Core`. It's not the only thing in that assembly though.

If you want LINQ to Objects but for .NET 2.0, there's [LINQBridge](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx).

If you want more than LINQ to Objects provides, you might want to look at [MoreLINQ](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/). (We have things like `DistinctBy`, `Concat` for individual items, `MinBy`, `MaxBy` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at

[www.extensionmethod.net](http://www.extensionmethod.net/)