# How to update an element with a List using LINQ and C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ienumerable, linq-to-objects

I have a list of objects and I'd like to update a particular member variable within one of the objects. I understand LINQ is designed for query and not meant to update lists of immutable data. What would be the best way to accomplish this? I do not need to use LINQ for the solution if it is not most efficient.

Would creating an Update extension method work? If so how would I go about doing that?

```
EXAMPLE:
(from trade in CrudeBalancedList
 where trade.Date.Month == monthIndex
 select trade).Update(
 trade => trade.Buy += optionQty);
```

Comment: I saw this entry and felt linking to it would be appropriate for anyone looking my question up. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344140/extension-method-for-update-in-linq-to-objects

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Although linq is not meant to update lists of immutable data, it is very handy for getting the items that you want to update.  I think for you this would be:

```
(from trade in CrudeBalancedList
    where trade.Date.Month == monthIndex
    select trade).ToList().ForEach( trade => trade.Buy += optionQty);
```

Comment: This will generate a new updated list or it will update CrudeBalancedList?

Comment: At the point of the ToList() method being called, there's is a list of trade objects that meet the criteria.  There's no variable for this list, so it will be a target for garbage collection as soon as this line is executed.  If you wanted to utilize this list for more than just doing [trade.Buy += optionQty], then you would want to separate out this line of code to several others.  First define and set a variable like so:  List<trade> monthlyCrudeBalancedList = (from trade in etc.  Then next line:  monthlyCrudeBalancedList.ForEach( trade => etc.   Then, you'd have a reference to the new list.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this is the best way, but will allow you to update an element from the list.

The test object:

```
 public class SomeClass {
        public int Value { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    }
```

The extension method:

```
public static class Extension {
        public static void Update<T>(this T item, Action<T> updateAction) {
            updateAction(item);
        }
    }
```

The test:

```
public void Test()
{
    // test data
    List<SomeClass> list = new List<SomeClass>()
    {
        new SomeClass {Value = 1, Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)},
        new SomeClass {Value = 2, Date = DateTime.Now },
        new SomeClass {Value = 3, Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)}
    };
    // query and update
    (from i in list where i.Date.Day.Equals(DateTime.Now.Day) select i).First().Update(v => v.Value += 5);

    foreach (SomeClass s in list) {
        Console.WriteLine(s.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: or you can just do it like:  `(from i in list where i.Date.Day.Equals(DateTime.Now.Day) select i).First().Value+=4;`

Answer (score 1):

So you're expecting to get a single result here. In that case you might consider utilizing the `SingleOrDefault` method:

```
var record =
    (from trade in CrudeBalancedList
    where trade.Date.Month == monthIndex
    select trade).SingleOrDefault();

if (record != null)
    record.Buy += optionQty;
```

Note that the `SingleOrDefault` method expects there to be **exactly one or zero** value returned (much like a row in a table for some unique primary key). If more than one record is returned, the method will throw an exception.

Comment: Or use the similar FirstOrDefault method.  It will not throw an exception if more than one record is returned.

Answer (score 0):

To create such a method, you would start with its prototype:

```
public static class UpdateEx {
    public void Update(this IEnumerable<T> items, 
                       Expression<Action> updateAction) {
    }
}
```

That's the easy part.

The hard part will be to **compile** the `Expression<Action>` into an SQL update statement. Depending on how much syntax you want to support, such a compiler's complexity can range from trivial to impossible.

For an example of compiling Linq Expressions, see the `TableQuery` class of the [sqlite-net project](http://code.google.com/p/sqlite-net/source/browse/trunk/src/SQLite.cs).